# Why does this javascript regex.match capture 3 groups where I only expect 2?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to format a Belgian VAT number as `BE0.###.###.###`. The 9 last digits can enter prefixed by `BE`, `BE0` or by nothing at all.. I'm using the following javascript number:

```
function BEVATFormat(vatnumber) {
    var numbers = vatnumber.match(/^(BE)?(0?\d{9})$/)[1];
    var letters = "BE0";
    if (numbers.length == 10) {
        numbers = numbers.slice(1);
    }
    numbers = numbers.match(/\d{1,3}/g).join(".");
    return letters + "." + numbers;
}
```

I expected this to return only 2 matches, because I only got 2 capturing groups. However, I am finding that there are 3 groups: first the entire input, then the BE and then the digits. Why is this?

I should clarify why I'm not expecting this result. When I'm trying to format an IBAN number by grouping 4 characters, I use:

```
ibanNumber.match(/.{1,4}/g).join(" ");
```

which doesn't do this. It's also not that big a deal because I can simply increment the index I have to get by 1.

---

After considering the answer I accepted, I altered my code to use:

```
function BEVATFormat(vatnumber) {
    var numbers = vatnumber.match(/0?(\d{9})$/)[1];
    var letters = "BE 0";
    numbers = numbers.match(/\d{1,3}/g).join(".");
    return letters + numbers;
}
```

because all I need from the number is the last 9 digits. This way, if there's no BE or 0 in there, the index of the numbers I need does not change.

Comment: Because that's how `.match()` is supposed to work with sub-matches. The first element in the returned array is the string that matched the whole regex, which in your case happens to be the whole input.

Comment: Following what you've described I'd rather use such regex: /^(BE0?)?(\d{9})$/

Comment: @nnnnnn I see. Could you give that as an answer so I can upvote and accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use [`.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) with a regex that doesn't have the global `g` flag, the resulting array's first element is the string that the whole regex matched, and subsequent array elements are the sub groups matched. That is, the behaviour you describe is normal and correct.

In your case the first element returned is the whole input because that's what your regex matched.

The second use of `.match()` in your code uses a regex that *does* have the `g` flag (and doesn't have any sub groups), so that's why it behaves differently.

(Note that with or without the `g` flag if there are no matches at all you'll get `null` back, not an empty array.)